# Windows annoying when typing "'s by waiting for a combining character

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, keyboard-layout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Weird keyboard issue](https://superuser.com/questions/215409/weird-keyboard-issue)

Not strictly speaking a programming question but something that annoys me to no end while programming.

Win7 keeps waiting for a character to be typed after a ", ', ^ etc. How do I turn that off?

Answer (score 0):

Change your keyboard layout to something that doesn't have dead keys.  Go to Control Panel, search for "keyboard Layout", and click "Change Keyboards or other input methods".  When the Region and Language control panel appears, click "Change Keyboards...", and then click "Add" to add a new keyboard layout.

Since you didn't say what your existing keyboard layout is, I can't guide you further.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I tried that before... Lemme check...

Answer (score 0):

this should be moved to superuser, but most likely your problem is that your keyboard layout is set to something funky.  try setting it to English (United States) - US keyboard

Comment: Sorry, didn't know about superuser. I tried that, didn't fix it. Tried to find what else could be causing it. Eventually found what it appears to have been. Unlike previous versions it's not the keyboard setting (or it only works after a reboot), it's the system locale. Switched that to US and then it works.

Back to programming! Thanks!