# Weird keyboard issue

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, keyboard-layout

Hi i just got a weird keyboard issue and i don't have any idea how this happened.
When i press certain keys the character does not appear instantly but it waits for another key and then depending on that key it displays the two pressed chars or another char formed from the two pressed keys.

This happens everywhere, Firefox, Notepad, etc...
The keys that do these are `' " ^ ~`
For example if i press `"` nothing shows and if my next key is `e` i get `ë`, if it's something else, like space, then i get the normal `"` as expected.
Any idea how to fix this? It is really annoying. 
I'm using Windows 7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go into your keyboard control panel and change from the US-International layout to the US layout.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that some countries have more accent than we have keys. So to solve this problem they have invented this weird system where you click on a ' before and then on the letter. So '+e would often create an é. You should go in the preferences and change the type of keyboard you have. I don't have unfortunately a windows from many years so I cannot guide you to that. But this is the general idea.